# Expand aliases in tcsh

Tags: alias, tcsh, expansion

It looks like in bash it is `alias-expand-line`.

What is the bindkey command I can add to my .cshrc_custom file?

Sort of related: what is `"^[y"` referring to for a key bind? I know `^` is `ctrl`, but what is `[`?

Comment: Is there at least a way to do it in bash or zsh?

Comment: `^[` is control-left-bracket, equivalent to the Escape key.

Answer (score 7):

Running `man tcsh` and searching for "alias" yields:

> **normalize-command** (^X-?)
>       Searches for the current word in PATH and, if it is found, replaces it
>       with the full path to the executable.  Special characters are quoted.
>       Aliases are expanded and  quoted but commands within aliases are not.
>       This command is useful with commands that take commands as arguments,
>       e.g., ‘dbx’ and ‘sh -x’.

For example:

```
% alias hi echo hello
% hi
```

Typing <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd> when the cursor is immediately after the `hi` expands it to `echo hello`. And since it's already bound, you don't necessarily need to touch your startup file (unless you want to change the binding).

One problem: It expands to the definition of the alias, not necessarily to what the alias would have expanded to. For example, given:

```
% alias echo2 'echo \!:2'
```

(which echos just its second argument), typing `echo2` followed by <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd> expands it literally to `echo !:2`.

Comment: This is extremly cool, can I do this ? expand  `echo2 myArg` to `echo myArg` ?